# Close as dupe of OP's example because he doesn't understand basics?

Tags: discussion

So, someone asked an Android question. They are apparently clueless in Java basics but that's ok (I was at one point maybe still am). I gave an answer on how to make it work for now so they could learn something. I quickly deleted the answer because it isn't the way it *should* be done.

I also saw the OP comment on the SO post he got the code from but completely missed some major points clearly illustrated in the "example post".

I really want to close as a dupe of the one the OP posted in a comment he was "following" but not sure if that's right.

I can add links if necessary but was trying to keep from the meta effect.

No answer is going to be helpful to other users without pointing out everything in the linked post and going step-by-step through it.

Comment: Add a comment asking him to clarify what he does not understand, resp. advising him to read a basic tutorial, and vote to close as "unclear" or "too broad". Depending on the post, a downvote *might* be in order. Though keep in mind I'm advising kind of blindly depending completely on your description.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did comment but he obviously doesn't understand the basics of Java or Android. Here is the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822281/why-is-my-check-edittext-empty-not-working

Comment: @Deduplicator I can just answer telling him that he forgot to attach the listener and how to do it a little more efficiently. Thanks for responding But the problem is that he isn't doing what the target answer specifically suggests as an answer. So my answer would basically be an exact dupe of that answer and many others.

Comment: Well... crap. Sometimes, there's no good way forward but suggesting the asker should start reading the basics. But you already did, so just closing is left. Dupe-closing looks ok.

Comment: @Deduplicator close or make it more obvious of the problem and add a better way to do it? Because that answer could actually be improved.

Comment: Close as dupe, and add a better answer to the target, if you have one.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point. Thanks, I will do that